# Using HTA in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, hta, wsh

While using HTA userform for VBscript, I found that HTA doesn't support WScript and its objects/methods.

Is there any alternate way of creating userform or is thery any way to make HTA support WScript?

Comment: Which WScript members do you need to use? Perhaps there are alternatives

Comment: I am using WScript.Echo and FileSystemObject objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to `WScript.Echo` would be to simply add content to the DOM:

```
<script language="vbscript">
    dim div: set div = document.getElementById("output")
    div.innerText = "output"
</script>

<div id="output"/>
```

or if you want a dialogbox instead, you can use `MsgBox()`

```
<script language="vbscript">
    MsgBox "output"
</script>
```

You can use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` without `WScript`

```
<script language="vbscript">
    dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    dim path: path = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
    '... etc
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your `Wscript` code to a [`.wsf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d5a2tx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)-file and call the script like this:

```
shell=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
shell.Exec('WScript //Job:job_id PATH_TO_YOUR_WSF_FILE');
```

Via `.wsf` you can use also methods like `WScript.Sleep()`, `WScript.SendKeys()` etc. which are not available in HTA.

More info at MSDN: [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: I am actually calling vbs file from bat file. Then from vbs I am calling HTA form to get user input and with inputs performing actions based on inputs.

Comment: Something like [this](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/An-HTA-based-VBScript-36122f57)? If so, you need to `HTABox.document.write` the JScript I suppose.

Comment: Now I have got an idea to call HTA file from bat file. But is it possible to fetch data from hta to batch file?

Comment: I'd be glad if you could tell me, how to interact between windows. I've used temporary files, which is working fine, except you can't pass real objects...

Comment: I will pass arguments to hta file like this: 
@call scripts\UserForm.hta "src" "dest" "op"

Later in hta, i will store values in these arguments so that i can use them in bat file. 
I dont know if this makes sense or not

Comment: I know I can read `commandLine` from HTA, but how/where to store `returnValue` and read it in a different app/win?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure it out.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Like I said in the comment above, I create a temporary text file to the HD, and read it in the "receiver" app, then delete the file.

Comment: @Teemu: Thanks. Here is a copy of the original article: https://web.archive.org/web/20200318070426/http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/An-HTA-based-VBScript-36122f57