# Why do I get a "necessary object" error on objShell?

Tags: html, testing, vbscript, hta

I don't know why I'm getting an error on the `Set objShell =` statement of this VBS code (it's in an HTML). I'm working on a .HTA launcher for a game named Doom and this VBScript serves to select the game and launch it with some parameters.

```
Dim pwad, warp, skill, execDoom, execPwad, execWarp, execSkill, rep, fso, file, OpFScript, WScript, objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set pwad = document.GetElementById("inpFILE")
Set warp = document.GetElementById("inpMAP")
Set skill = document.GetElementById("inpSKILL")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\ZDLRemastered\launcher\ScriptOpFile.txt", 1)
OpFScript = file.ReadAll

Function GetFileDlgEx(sIniDir,sFilter,sTitle) 
    Set oDlg = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("mshta.exe & OpFScript")
    oDlg.StdIn.Write "var iniDir='" & sIniDir & "';var filter='" & sFilter & "';var title='" & sTitle & "';" 
    GetFileDlgEx = oDlg.StdOut.ReadAll 
End Function

sFilter = "Doom Archive (*.wad)|*.wad|"  
sTitle = "Select a Doom IWAD"
rep = GetFileDlgEx(Replace(sIniDir,"\","\\"),sFilter,sTitle)

execDoom = "C:\ZDLRemastered\gzdoom\gzdoom.exe -config C:\ZDLRemastered\gzdoom\gzconfig.ini -iwad "
execPwad = " -file "
execWarp = " -warp "
execSkill = " -skill "
objShell.Run execDoom & Chr(34) & rep & Chr(34) & execPwad & Chr(34) & pwad & Chr(34) & execWarp & Chr(34) & warp & Chr(34) & execSkill & Chr(34) & skill & Chr(34)
```

This is the error:

> necessary object: " -

Comment: "necessary object" is not a VBScript error message. Is this something you translated from a localized message?

Comment: Also, in an HTA there is no `WScript` object. Use `CreateObject()` instead of `WScript.CreateObject()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTA in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813507/using-hta-in-vbscript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Object required: 'wscript' in HTA](//stackoverflow.com/q/40476304)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTAs run in a different engine than regular VBScript (`mshta.exe` vs `wscript.exe`/`cscript.exe`). The HTA engine does not provide an intrinsic `WScript` object, hence `WScript.CreateObject()` or `WScript.Sleep()` or `WScript.Quit()` won't work.

That intrinsic object isn't required for creating objects, though, since VBScript also has a global function `CreateObject()` (which is [not the same as `WScript.CreateObject()`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/06/01/whats-the-difference-between-wscript-createobject-server-createobject-and-createobject/)).

Change this:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

into this:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: You [already answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40476304/692942) over 2.5 years ago.

Comment: @Lankymart I've posted a couple thousand answers over the past years. Excuse me for not remembering every single one of them.